# When someone gets you wrong and you are going to explain them that they've got you wrong

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Please imagine you say someone something and that person gets you wrong. You want to explain them that their taking has been wrong. I was wondering if someone could let me know which one of the following self-made sentences sounds more idiomatic in this sense:

> - Wait, I think **you are misunderstanding me**...
> - Wait, I think **you got me wrong**...
> - Wait, I think **you got it wrong**...
> - Wait, I think **you took it the wrong way**...
> - Wait, I think **you took it twisted**...

For me, they all work properly , but I don't have any idea which one is in common use in English.

Comment: If you are talking about something you said and someone didn't get it right,  like if I didn't get your question and answered it in another way, so you could say: _I think you misunderstood me_
But all others seem to fit in this context, _misunderstand_ has been the most used.

Comment: All except for the *twisted* example are good. We have an expression, "You're twisting my words" which means "You are *deliberately* trying to  distort what I said."  You could say "You *got* it twisted" or "You have it backwards", which would mean that the listener had reversed something.  For example, "No, you got it twisted. Bill is from London and Mike is from Manchester".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the above answers do make sense they come off as blaming the other person.
I would instead try something like

> I think there has been some miscommunication.

This way no one is being blamed but the issue is still raised.

Answer (score 5):

They are all used, however a different form of the first one:

> I think you *misunderstood* me

Is more appropriate because it is said after the misunderstanding happens. The rest are at varying degrees of formality and some don't have the actual meaning that you intend:

> You got me wrong

This is sometimes used, but its informal and more colloquial.

> You got it wrong

This is also used when something else (not what you have said) is misunderstood. For example, if someone confuses directions to a destination. It is not something you have said, but something they have misunderstood.

> You took it the wrong way

This is for when someone understood you, but had a different reaction than you expected. In this case the meaning was understood but the intent was not. For example, when someone takes a compliment the wrong way, or assumes sarcasm when you are being sincere.

> You took it twisted

Personally I have never heard this expression - but it can imply the same thing as *you took it the wrong way*; as getting something twisted (around) is often used when someone does not understand the intention.